# How to add an image slider with dots indicator inside a fragment?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am new to android, I want to add a image slider with dots indicator inside a class which has been extended to Fragment.I want to add the image slider in fragment_about_sl.xml(code is shown below) and the back end of that in aboutSLFragment.java(code shown below).How can I do that and please tell me the full code to implement.

**fragment_about_sl.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hkjhkjhkjhk"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**aboutSLFragment.java**

```
public class aboutSLFragment extends Fragment {



public aboutSLFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_sl, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("About Sri Lanka");
}

}
```

**I have extended aboutSLFragment.java to Fragment, because I used fragments when creating my navigation drawer. Please tell me what to add to the xml and java class.Thank you!**

I've added the image slider to my class but there are some errors in red.Can anybody help.I have bolded the red colored errors.
    public class aboutSLFragment extends Fragment{

```
ViewPager viewPager;
LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
private int dotscount;
private ImageView[] dots;


public aboutSLFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    viewPager = (ViewPager) **findViewById**(R.id.viewPager);

    sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout) **findViewById**(R.id.SliderDots);

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(**this**);

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
    dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

    for(int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){

        dots[i] = new ImageView(**this**);
        dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(**getApplicationContext()**, R.drawable.non_active_dot));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

        sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

    }

    dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(**getApplicationContext()**, R.drawable.active_dot));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            for(int i = 0; i< dotscount; i++){
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(**getApplicationContext()**, R.drawable.non_active_dot));
            }

            dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(**getApplicationContext()**, R.drawable.active_dot));

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_sl, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("About Sri Lanka");
}

}
```

Comment: for the image slider you can use `ViewPager`. And find or build yourself an indicator with dots for it.

Comment: I know that.Please if you have a source code please show me

Comment: we are not welcome to write code instead of you. It is you and only you who should write your code. Show your efort and tell us what is the problem, and we will try to help

Comment: hello Vlad Matvienko, I addedd an image slider but it has some errors which I can't resolve.Could you please have a look at that and tell me how to correct that.I have bolded the errors.thank you

Comment: Next time you ask question here be sure to add the error text as well. You absolutely have to do that. Because in most cases it is not obvious which error you get. But here I see which errors you get. And you get them because you are missing basic knowladge about Java and Fragments. You really have to take some basic lessongs before you continue. And to solve these errors try searching them before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited form of your code

```
ViewPager viewPager;
LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
private int dotscount;
private ImageView[] dots;


public aboutSLFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_sl, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity());

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
    dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

    for(int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){

        dots[i] = new ImageView(getActivity());
        dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.non_active_dot));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

        sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

    }

    dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            for(int i = 0; i< dotscount; i++){
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.non_active_dot));
            }

            dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("About Sri Lanka");
}

}
```